# LibreOffice Presenter export PDF with Video

Tags: libreoffice

I have a presentation that has a video embedded inside it. I want to export this presentation as a PDF with the video in it. Right now, instead of a video there is just an image with a question mark on it. The video works just fine from the presentation.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening the odp with something like 7-zip then edit the content.xml so the href to the movie rather than ../path/to/file.extension it is Video/file.extension
Then create a folder in the odp with 7-zip, call the folder Video, and place any file you have referenced in the content.xml in there. I am still testing this method myself, I'll let you know how I go once I get home to my Linux laptop and its libre office install.

Annoyingly that trick works to make your odp portable, but it doesn't work when you convert that ODP to a pd. Unfortunately this feature doesn't appear to be available on Impress at the moment. There is this guide, but it doesn't work for me. I think a feature request needs to be done.